# $(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1} C_\lambda)\,\bigcap\,(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2} A_\lambda)$ is a compact closed subspace of $S$. Is my proof ok?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I am reading a proof of a proposition about compactification.
In the proof, I guess the author uses the following proposition.

> Proposition 1:
> Let $S$ be a topological space.
> Let $C_\lambda$ be compact closed subspaces of $S$ for any $\lambda\in\Lambda_1$.
> Let $A_\lambda$ be closed subspaces of $S$ for any $\lambda\in\Lambda_2$.
> Then, $(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1} C_\lambda)\,\bigcap\,(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2} A_\lambda)$ is a compact closed subspace of $S$.

I think the above proposition is true.
I proved the above proposition as follows.
Is my proof ok or not?

First, I prove the following proposition:

> Proposition 2:
> Let $S$ be a topological space.
> Let $C$ be a compact subspace of $S$.
> Let $A$ be a closed subspace of $S$.
> Then, $C\cap A$ is a compact closed subspace of $S$.

My proof of Proposition 2:

> I use the fact that a closed subspace of a compact space is compact.
> Since $A$ is closed in $S$, $C\cap A$ is closed in $C$.
> Since $C\cap A$ is closed in a compact space $C$, $C\cap A$ is a compact in $C$.
> So, $C\cap A$ is a compact closed subspace of $C$.
> So, $C\cap A$ is a compact closed subspace of $S$.

My proof of Proposition 1:

> $(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1} C_\lambda)\,\bigcap\,(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2} A_\lambda)=C_{\lambda_0}\cap (\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1-\{\lambda_0\}} C_\lambda)\,\bigcap\,(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2} A_\lambda)$.
> $(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1-\{\lambda_0\}} C_\lambda)\,\bigcap\,(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2} A_\lambda)$ is a closed subspace of $S$.
> And $C_{\lambda_0}$ is a compact subspace of $S$.
> By Proposition 2, $(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1} C_\lambda)\,\bigcap\,(\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2} A_\lambda)$ is a compact closed subspace of $S$.

Comment: Proposition2: Compact sets need not be closed since $S$ is not known to be Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs are correct, in both cases you are using by definition of subspace topology that if $A\subset S$ is a closed(open) subspace of S , given $C$ compact, $C\cap A$ is a closed set in S, and compactness can be checked on a open cover(of open set in the subspace) of a subspace. Moreover you are using an hypothesis valid always which is that closed in a compact is compact.

Comment: giorgiokyn23, Thank you very much for your answer.